# continuous an open image of a meager set is meager

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, baire-category

I want to know if the following is true.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $f\colon X\to Y$  a continuous open surjection. Suppose that $X$ is meager, then $Y$ is meager.

Recall that a meager set is a countable union of nowhere dense sets, and a set is nowhere dense if the interior of its closure is empty.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of 'meager set'?

Comment: @Babai I just wrote the definitions in the body of the question.

Comment: So if you say that $X$ is meager, you mean that $X$ is meager in $X$ (i.e., the space $X$ is a countable union of nowhere dense subsets of $X$)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it is true,

Let $X= \mathbb{Q}$ which is clearly meager  & $Y$ is singleton. and let $f:X\to Y$  be constant map,  so has satisfied all the desired properties, but $Y$ is not meager, because any subset is open in $Y$ since it is singleton.